If $Y_i$ are i.i.d $> 0$, will the $\ln$ of the average exist if $E|\ln(Y_i)| < \infty$?
If $Y_i$ are i.i.d $> 0$, will the $\ln$ of the average exist if $E|\ln(Y_i)| < \infty$?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

This is most likely false. Some ideas : you probably will need to come up with a counterexample using lower bounds on $\ln$. For instance, by https://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf, if you can find example such that, with$X = \frac{Y_1}{Y_2}$, $X-X^2$ is not integrable, you will have a negative answer.

Apparently, it isn't. DCT is not applicable, and so far I was just able to show that
$ln(\bar{X_n})  \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^nln(X_i)$  [Jensesn's]
Don't know where to go from here other than showing that that perhaps the expecation on the LHS is bounded by the RHS?
